# Using Ajax posts (Bit confused)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am using an ajax post in a wordpress plugin to submit and validate form values. This is the first time I have used ajax though and am a bit confused as to how it works. This is my ajax post:

```
           jQuery.ajax({

                type:"post",
                dataType:"json",
                url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
                data: {action: 'submit_data', info: info},
                success: function(response) {
                    if (response.type == "success") {

                        alert("success");
                    }
                    else {

                        alert("fail");
                    }
                }
            });
```

This posts data to a php function named submit_data, shown here:

```
function submit_data() {

    $nameErr = $emailErr = $phoneErr = $commentErr = "";
    $full = explode("&", $_POST["info"]);
    $fname = explode(":", $full[0]);
    $name = $fname[1];
    $femail = explode(":", $full[1]);
    $email = $femail[1];
    $fphone = explode(":", $full[2]);
    $phone = $fphone[1];
    $fcomment = explode(":", $full[3]);
    $comment = $fcomment[1];

    if ((empty($name)) || (strlen($name) < 4)){

        $nameErr = "Please enter a name";
    }
    else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $name)) {

        $nameErr = "Please ensure you have entered your name and surname";
    }


    if (empty($email)) {

        $emailErr = "Please enter an email address";
    }
    else if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email)) {

        $emailErr = "Please ensure you have entered a valid email address";
    }


    if (empty($phone)) {

        $phoneErr = "Please enter a phone number";
    }
    else if (!preg_match("/(?:\(?\+\d{2}\)?\s*)?\d+(?:[ -]*\d+)*$/",$phone)) {

        $phoneErr = "Please ensure you have entered a valid phone number";
    }


    if ((empty($nameErr)) && (empty($emailErr)) && (empty($phoneErr)) && (empty($commentErr))) {

        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "Mikey", "Change0", "plugindatadb");
        mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO data (Name, Email, Phone, Comment) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$phone', '$comment')");
    }
    else {

        $errorArray = array();
        if (!empty($nameErr)) {

            $errorArray["nameErr"] = $nameErr;
        }
        if (!empty($emailErr)) {

            $errorArray["emailErr"] = $emailErr;
        }
        if (!empty($phoneErr)) {

            $errorArray["phoneErr"] = $phoneErr;
        }
        if (!empty($commentErr)) {

            $errorArray["commentErr"] = $commentErr;
        }

    }

    die();
}
```

My question is if the submit_data function runs successfully with no errors, does the code then run the ajax success function? Or does the ajax success function run before the end of submit_data is encountered?

Comment: You you have posted it again ?

Answer (score 0):

The success function in AJAX runs after it recieves a response from the server.

i.e. after the `submit_data` completes execution.

> **Error**:
> A function to be called if the request fails. The function receives three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object, a string describing the type of error that occurred and an optional exception object, if one occurred. Possible values for the second argument (besides null) are "timeout", "error", "abort", and "parsererror". When an HTTP error occurs, errorThrown receives the textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found" or "Internal Server Error."

---

> **success**
> A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted according to the dataType parameter; a string describing the status; and the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object.

[Reference](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: So if I were to then return the error messages from the submit_data function to the ajax post, would I be able to say:

Comment: echo json_encode("errors[]" => "$errorarray") and then reference it in my success function of the ajax post by "errors" ?